# какая сложность добавления элемента в массив в начало и в конец

Tags: php

столкнулся с таким вопросом. В интернете не нашел ответа

Comment: Создайте пустой массив и добавьте в конец 1млн элементов с измерением времени. Затем повторите, добавляя в начало и узнаете )

Comment: А в php массивы - настоящие массивы в едином куске памяти, или на самом деле словари?

Comment: @MBo насколько я знаю, сишных массивов там не бывает. но перестроение индекса даст, по идее, большое время. Впрочем, я не разбирался, возможно вру

Comment: @splash58 Ну собственно я и хотел обратить внимание на нетривиальность для PHP. Про `array_unshift` пишется именно так, как вы сказали: `All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero`

Answer (score 1):

В общем-то сложность должна быть одинаковая. Если говорить про алгоритмическую сложность. По своей внутренней реализации массив в PHP это map. А в map элементы добавляются с одинаковой сложностью.

Есть один момент с перемчетом индексов, если индексы являются целыми числами. Т.е. в случае если добавляется элемент в начало массива с числовыми индексами, то, по идее, меняются индексы у всех элементов. В этом и может быть единственное различие.

Много информации про массивы в PHP есть в официальной инструкции: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего добавление в конец - проще для системы, добавила и все.
При этом добавление в начало, требует сдвига всех элементов\индексов на 1 вперед